# OSX - pathname for file outside Sites folder

Tags: html, macos, localhost, pathname

I've set up a local Git repository outside my `Sites` folder. In hindsight, this was possibly a mistake.

I want to test one of the Git files, but my test html page needs to be inside the `Sites` folder to run with Apache under `~localhost`.

So can I get the html page `http://~localhost/MyUserName/test.html` (which has the path `MyUserName/Sites/test.html`) to find the script with the path `MyUserName/GitHub/myScript.js`? Or does the Git folder need to move to be within `Sites`?

I tried the following without success:

`<script src="../GitHub/myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference files outside the webroot (your Sites folder, in this case); that would potentially allow access to any file on your machine.

If you want to solve this without moving your repo, you can symlink your GitHub dir into your Sites folder. On OS X, Apache should follow symlinks by default; if not, you can place a .htaccess file with `Options +FollowSymlinks` in the Sites folder to turn it on. (You can find the docs on [Apache's `Options` directive here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)).

Comment: For anyone who finds this question, I found the following utility extremely helpful when my symbolic links weren't working properly: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10433/symboliclinker